# Icons are not displayed in the ASP Tree view control

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I'm currently facing an issue with my ASP control "tree view"; the icons are not displayed properly:

[image: Issue]

when I try to debug I get the following error message in Javascript:

> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;
>   Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR
>   3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E) Timestamp: Tue, 13 Aug 2013 14:14:09 UTC
>
> Message: Object expected Line: 527 Char: 1 Code: 0 URI:
>   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

I'm not sure I understand why I'm facing this issue since I'm simply using the ASP tree-view control. Maybe the images are "blocked" by IIS/proxy ?

Any idea what is causing this issue?

Best regards,